# Fullscreen graphics problem.

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, fullscreen, toshiba-satellite

Whenever I make a YouTube video, Minecraft, The Sims 3 (in wine), or I assume any other application into full-screen the desktop environment starts to flicker and go crazy. occasionally when I try to take a screen shot pressing the button actually stops the flickering, as well as turning up or down the volume. I found this to be quite curious. Things still work but if you open an application it will flicker away and come back and things change according to where the mouse pointer is. The problem is solved when I log out and back in or if I restart. It is becoming a nuance because I make things full-screen without thinking.

I am running 12.04 on a Toshiba Satellite L300. I am upgrading soon but Christmas is still a long way away! From my experience because it has Intel integrated graphics I don't need to update like I would with nivida? I am just an average Joe user who is 16 so I have a smallish knowledge and grasp things easy but I am not that technical. So if you could explain things to that level it would help a lot :)

Thank you in advance, sorry about my spelling.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with your intel gfx card drivers, go to this [link](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intel-linux-graphics-installer) and download the u12.04-downgrade.tar and follow the steps listed on the website.

But before you do that i would like to make sure you don't have any drivers installed. 
Here's how to do it:

System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers tab

Tell me what you see.

Comment: It says:

No proprietary drivers are in use on this system.

Comment: Ok then do what i told you. If i works mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: I tried but failed to follow the instructions. From my understanding I had to put the last two steps into the terminal? Yet when I did they wouldn't work. Even when I used sudo or sudo su?

Comment: they didn't work as in you got an error after entering the 2 signatures for ubuntu or? Because after you have done that you suppose to have double clicked the .tar file which will open you the software center from which you will install the program

Comment: I AM SO SORRY! the .tar  file you had to extract it and then execute the downgrade.sh file

Comment: I allowed the .sh file to be executed however I try to run it in terminal and the terminal window just closes suddenly.

Comment: I will try to replicate the issue on 12.04 and will inform you as soon as im done

Comment: So I decided to just open the .sh and copy its contents into the terminal. Everything works, I type Y to continue and it aborts. Any Ideas how I can get this to run?

Comment: putting -y in front of install let it work. however Problem is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04, or better still, if you are doing screencasts try Xubuntu 13.04 instead and see if the newer drivers help with the flicker while recording...